# How do you notate a large range of discrete set values conforming to some consistent pattern?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

E.g., A={1,3,5,..,3047}.
Suppose that B and C are mutually exclusive proper subsets of A, where {C}={[¬B]⋂[A]} and {B}={[¬A]⋂[C]} suggesting that {B}⋂{C} = {A}.  Suppose further than {C} has only a few elements, say {11,2053}.  What, in that case, would be the most concise and/or correct way to list the complete set of {B} without reference to {C}?

What if the elements are not discrete but either continuous value ranges or a combination of discrete values and value ranges, but still conform to some pattern or equation? E.g., suppose that F={(-2 to 4],(6 to 12],(14 to 20],...,(208 to 214]} with complementary proper subsets G and H. For simplicity, suppose that H consists only of {(128 to 134]}. How then concisely but fully can {G} be stated without reference to {H}?

Comment: I don't think you want $\{B\}$ here.  That is the set that contains the set $B$.  Similar comment for $C$, $G$, and $H$.  Also, what do the square brackets indicate?  And does $\neg$ indicate complement with respect to $A$?

Comment: By [C] I meant the domain of set C. By {C} I mean the entirity of C's contents without depending on C itself, though you are probably right in that being non-correct. And yes the negation in this context means complement with respect to the 'parent' set.

Comment: Traditional notation would be $A=B \cup C, B \cap C = \emptyset, B = A \setminus C, C = A \setminus B.$

Comment: What does the backslash mean and read as in English in this usage?

Comment: The backslash indicates set complement, and you can pronounce it as "set minus" or "minus": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)

Comment: Thank you for that information.    What about my original question? I.e. a set ('B') of odd integers from 1 to 3,047 excluding 11 and 2,053: how would you state explicitly those values as contained within and constituting entirety of B?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mention $C$:
$$B = A \setminus \{11,2053\}$$

If you don't want to mention $C$ or $A$:
$$B = \{1,3,5,\dots,3047\} \setminus \{11,2053\}$$

Similarly, assuming you meant $F=(-2,4] \cup (6,12] \cup (14,20] \cup \dots \cup (208,214]$:
$$G = F \setminus (128,134]$$

Comment: ah, so the \ in set notation is analogous to minus sign outside of sets, similarly (if my understanding holds true) to union ∪ being analogous to plus-sign.  What would - or + symbols indicate with regards to sets? something along the lines of adding matrices?   Also, is there a formal translation of intersection ⋂ into non-sets? multiplication, division?